# Yii2 Auth choice render widget is not working

Tags: php, oauth, yii2, facebook-social-plugins

I am trying to social login with authClient and when adds widget to render it gives error :

```
Class 'yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice' not found
```

while Class is there.
widget code is :

```
 <?= yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
              'baseAuthUrl' => ['site/auth'],
              'popupMode' => false,
          ]) ?>
```

Comment: do you have `"yiisoft/yii2-authclient": "*"` in your composer.json ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it first

`composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-authclient "*"`

see [Installation guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/master/docs/guide/installation.md)